# Bug fix for the ddclient "Invalid IP" error not working

Tags: networking, dns, dyndns, ddclient

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 on a mid-2009 MacBook Pro and using ddclient to update my IP address at www.no-ip.com. After installing ddclient according to the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS) I had one successful update but none since.

My `/etc/ddclient.conf` looks like this:

```
daemon=3600
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid
#use=if, if=eth0
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com/, web-skip='IP Address'
protocol=noip
ssl=yes
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update
login=JDoe
password='JDoesPassword'
isauron.myftp.org
```

When I run `sudo ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet` I get:

```
WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache, line 3: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = ''
...
WARNING:  skipping update of Home from <nothing> to [real IP].
WARNING:   last updated <never> but last attempt on Mon Sep 10 09:06:05 2012 failed.
```

I've tried the solution described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64219/why-is-ddclient-giving-me-an-invalid-ip-error-when-trying-to-update-dynamic-dn) thread but after running both commands that izx mentions and restarting, the error above still persists thus leaving me unable to update my IP.

Any ideas as to what could be going on? And is there another way to apply the suggested patch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a free account on https://www.dnsomatic.com/, then you sent your ip update there (they have an easy `ddclient.conf`) they will sent it for you to no-ip.com (and dyndns, and many others if you wish)