# How can I get ddclient to work with freedns?

Tags: server, ddclient

I use the dynamic DNS service at freedns.afraid.org for my 12.04 server. I had assumed that the protocols would be standardised and that ddclient would just work, but apparently not. I get this message in /var/log/syslog:

```
ERROR: Invalid update URL (2): unexpected status ()
```

I tried to use the updated version of ddclient from the alternative PPA described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152534/103117), but then I hit this error:

```
FATAL:    Error loading the Perl module Digest::SHA1 needed for freedns update.
FATAL:     On Debian, the package libdigest-sha1-perl must be installed.
```

And when I try to install that package, I get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package libdigest-sha1-perl
```

Which leads me to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdigest-sha1-perl/+bug/993648), which apparently has no solution. How to proceed?

Comment: Relevant bug report: [ddclient can't be used in quantal: needs missing libdigest-sha1-perl](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1068884)

Comment: Looks like the bug is [fixed in 3.8.2](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/news/2013/12/ddclient-382-finally-released/), ddclient now works fine with freedns out of the box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until ddclient is [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ddclient/+bug/1068884), you can manually install the old module it wants:

```
sudo apt-get install cpanminus
cpanm --sudo Digest::SHA1
```

[Free DNS's clients page](https://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/freedns.clients.php) and `ddclient --help` provide sample ddclient configurations. Restart ddclient for changes to take effect:

```
sudo service ddclient restart
```

Comment: I prefer this to hacking ddclient itself, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get FreeDNS to work by simply editing these two lines in `/usr/sbin/ddclient`:

From:

```
my $sha1_loaded = eval {require Digest::SHA1};
```

To:

```
my $sha1_loaded = eval {require Digest::SHA};
```

From:

```
import  Digest::SHA1 (qw/sha1_hex/);
```

To:

```
import Digest::SHA (qw/sha1_hex/);
```

Answer (score 2):

A [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdigest-sha1-perl/+bug/993648/comments/5) in the bug report suggests that it is "easy to change programs to use Digest::SHA instead of Digest::SHA1".

So the full steps are, first, because add-apt-repository is not installed by default:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then, as [described](https://askubuntu.com/a/152534/103117) by izx:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/ppa
```

Now, this repository contains many packages, but we only want ddclient. So make a preferences file such as `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nathan-prefs and edit it to look like this:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-nathan-renniewaldock
Pin-Priority: 400

Package: ddclient
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-nathan-renniewaldock
Pin-Priority: 500
```

Now install ddclient:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ddclient
```

Now, become root and edit /usr/sbin/ddclient. Look for `require Digest::SHA1` and replace it with `require Digest::SHA`. Then look for `import  Digest::SHA1` a few lines later and replace it with `import  Digest::SHA`.

Finally, open up /etc/ddclient.conf and make it look something like this (note the protocol):

```
daemon=3600
protocol=freedns
use=if, if=eth0
ssl=yes
use=web, web=myip.dnsomatic.com
server=freedns.afraid.org
login=username
password='password'
mydomain.example.com
```

The main thing I'm not happy about is hacking a file and breaking Ubuntu's package management. A better solution would be to get the PPA fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You can get it from:
[libdigest-sha1-perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdigest-sha1-perl/2.13-1build1/+build/2486961)

You may need to also install **libio-socket-ssl-perl**. Check your syslog

Comment: N: Unable to locate package libdigest-sha1-perl